# 2 different condition on one SQL query

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables. I need to pick some ids from table one and based one condition and insert into table 2. The second column again must come from tableA but based on a different condition

Table A

```
NC 1
NC 2
SC 3
SC 4
```

Table B

```
   1 100
    1 200
    2 100
    2 200
```

I want to insert rows to table B so it would look like this....

```
1 100
1 200
2 100
2 200
3 100
3 200
4 100
4 200
```

I am picking 3 and 4 from table A based on the state condtion = 'SC'and now I want to know how to pick the values of 100 and 200 which NC has...

Sorry if I havent worded it correctly

Comment: Your logic is not clear.  How do you associate `100` with `3` and `200` with `4`?  What happens if there are more or less than two rows?

Comment: Sorry... my question is incorrect.

Comment: I have corrected my question

Comment: It's still not clear what you want to achieve. It seems more a problem in your business logic than a technical problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-- sample data
create table tbla (code char(2), id int);
insert into tbla values ('NC', 1);
insert into tbla values ('NC', 2);
insert into tbla values ('SC', 3);
insert into tbla values ('SC', 4);

create table tblb (id int, value int);
insert into tblb values (1, 100);
insert into tblb values (1, 200);
insert into tblb values (2, 100);
insert into tblb values (2, 200);

-- your query to INSERT the new rows into tblb
insert into tblb
select x.id, y.value
from
(
    select distinct a.id
    from tbla a
    where a.code = 'SC'
) x
cross join
(
    select distinct b.value
    from tbla a
    join tblb b on a.id = b.id
    where a.code = 'NC' 
) y
left join tblb b on b.id = x.id and b.value = y.value
where b.id is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by a query like :

```
Select a.id, b.value
from "Table A" a
join "Table B" b
 on b.id=1 --This condition pick the two first rows on table B.
where a.condtion = 'SC'
```

This is not a elegant solution, but it work.